# Is Mt. Horeb the same as Mt Sinai?

Tags: theology, har-sinai

It says in the Torah that G-d spoke to the Jews on Mt. Sinai then later on in the Torah it says G-d spoke to the Jews on Mt. Horeb, so which Mt. did G-d really speak to the Jews on.

Moses called all of Israel and said to them: 'Hear, O Israel, the decrees and the ordinances that I speak in your ears today ― learn them, and be careful to perform them. The Lord your God sealed a covenant with us at Horev [Mount Sinai]. Not with our forefathers did God seal this covenant, but with us ― we who are here, all of us alive today. Face to face did God speak with you on the mountain from amid the fire.' (Deut. 5:1-4)

Comment: Yes see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biblical_Mount_Sinai)

Comment: Is there a reason that the same place cannot have multiple names? Many people refer to New York City as NYC or just New York, and colloquially it's also called "the Big Apple" and "the five Burroughs." Why not something as iconic to the nation as the Sinaitic experience?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/61477/why-is-the-mountain-sinai-called-chorev-as-well/61478#61478 AND http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/27437/why-was-there-a-covenant-cut-with-the-benei-yisrael-at-sinai-then-at-chorev-a